# Facebook KeyNotFoundException Even Though the Key Exists

Tags: c#, facebook, dictionary, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

So I am using the Facebook Unity API and can't figure out why I get `KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.`

I'm trying to get the last name of the user. First name works fine. I print the Facebook response in the line before which includes the "last_name" key but I still get the exception.

```
void APICallback(){
    Dictionary<string,string> profile = Util.DeserializeJSONProfile(result.Text);  
    print (result.Text);
    currentUser["Name"] = profile["first_name"];
    currentUser["LastName"] = profile["last_name"];
}
```

This is the `result.Text`:

```
{"id":"XXXXXXX","first_name":"David","last_name":"Richard","friends":{"data":[],"summary":{"total_count":58}}}
```

Comment: If you print profile what does it contain?

Comment: System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String] I'm not sure how to print a full dictionary in Unity

Comment: iterate through it and print the keys

Comment: ok so i did that and all it printed was the "first_name" key. But the result includes "id" and "last_name". I don't get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has got to be a bug with `Util.DerializeJSONProfile` I used SimpleJson to parse `result.Text` and it works perfectly.